# Unity Engine: Send a tcp MIDI (hex) message to a socket

Tags: unity-game-engine, hex, tcpclient, midi

I need to control an Allen&Heat device with a Unity program. The protocol to control the device is here: [A&H Midi protocol](https://www.allen-heath.com/media/AHM-TCP-Protocol-V1.1.pdf)
This is my script:

```
public void SendAllenDecrementGroup(string message){
    Byte[] byteMsg = new Byte[] {0xB2, 0x63, 0x00, 0xB2, 0x62, 0x20, 0xB2, 0x06, 0x3F};
    //Message: CH,x  -> Ch = id  x = 1 (invio singolo), x = 2 (invio multiplo)
    string ch = message.Split(",")[0];
    string x = message.Split(",")[1];
    if (ch == "00"){
        byteMsg = new Byte[] {0xB2, 0x63, 0x00, 0xB2, 0x62, 0x20, 0xB2, 0x06, 0x3F};
    }else if (ch == "01"){
        byteMsg = new Byte[] {0xB2, 0x63, 0x01, 0xB2, 0x62, 0x20, 0xB2, 0x06, 0x3F};
    }if (ch == "02"){
        byteMsg = new Byte[] {0xB2, 0x63, 0x02, 0xB2, 0x62, 0x20, 0xB2, 0x06, 0x3F};
    }
    socketConnection = new TcpClient();
 
    try{
        socketConnection.ConnectAsync(ipAllen, portAllen).Wait(2000);
        theStream = socketConnection.GetStream();
        theStream.Write(byteMsg, 0, byteMsg.Length); 
    }catch{
        Error("Impossibile connettersi al sistema. \nControllare la connessione e riprovare");
    }
    socketConnection.Close();
}
```

I tested the script with Hercules TCP Server and this is what it receive:

[image]

The message 1 is from PacketSender software. The message 2 is from my script. they are identical.
If I try to use my script with Allen&Heat it doesn't work.
If I try to use PacketSender with Allen&Heat it works!

What am I missing? the messages are the same but with mine doesn't work.

Comment: They just look like identical, you may write a tcp server to receive the bytes from PacketSender then compare them with what your program send.

Comment: I tried but the bytes are identical too. I can't undestand where is the problem...